# How do I make the divs inline?

Tags: css, html, inline

I am using a wrapper but I am pretty confused. I want the two `resultbox` `div`s to be in line with the `submit` `div`.

Take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QtVwr/

What am I doing wrong?

I'm not very familiar with CSS.

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle is broken.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QtVwr/1/ try this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that there are issues with your HTML.  Here's a start:

1. make sure all the `div`s are closed.
2. remove the `float`s from your css
3. add `display:inline-block;`
4. remove the inline styles from your HTML.
5. correct the `.wrapper` class to be `.wrapper1` (matching the HTML)

So, this is more what you want, I assume:

```
.wrapper1 {
    height:70px;
    width: 800px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    color: #BDBDBD;
}

.resultbox {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
}

.submit {
    height:15px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="resultbox" style="" >
        <div class="locationresult" style=""  form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search"  size="36" value="" style="" />
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="resultbox" style="" >
        <div class="locationresult" style=""  form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search"  size="36" value="" style="" />
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="resultbox" style="width:35px;" >
       <div class="submit"></div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QtVwr/2/

You will still need to fiddle with it.  But this is a start.

Answer (score 2):

To make `div` inline you should use the following CSS style:

```
.mydiv{ display: inline; }
```

Note: Change width of your wrapper (make it smaller) and you will see the results

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code you have provided.

- you have defined css rules for a class wrapper but use class wrapper1 in your html
- class wrapper doesn't have enough width for both of the result boxes plus the submit
- There are extra quotes on the second result box `style="margin-left: 5px;  margin-top: 3px;""`
- form tags are malformed and being intertwined with your div tags
- form tags aren't closed
- locationresult div tag isn't closed
- floats need to be cleared

here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e3dg6/

Answer (score 0):

The width of your results boxes combined exceeds the width of your wrapper. You need to either make the wrapper wider or reduce the width on the resultboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the submit div within a resultbox div?
Why the margin-left:10px, only with the first div?

I'd do it like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="resultbox"></div>
<div class="resultbox"></div>
<div id="submit"></div>
</div>
```

And set the width and height of the wrapper, and let the other divs float. It's just a longshot, not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. I just think your nesting is not okay.